# Hibernate is adding unique constraint while generating ddl for my sql

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-boot

Am using hibernate and spring boot with mySql db.
Have DDL mode enabled which is generating sql.
But dont know why it is adding **unique** constraint in each alter table.
**I dont want unique** for most of my reference but still hibernate is adding it.

```
@Entity
public class Users extends BaseEntity {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
private Long id;

@Size(max = 100)
@NotNull
private String username;

@Size(max = 150)
@NotNull
private String password;

@Size(max = 100)
@NotNull
@Column(unique = true)
private String email;

@JoinColumn(name = "role_id",**unique=false**)
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER ,optional = false)
private Role role;

}



@Entity
public class Role implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@Column(name = "role_id",nullable = false)
private Integer roleId;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Size(max = 10)
@Column(name = "role_type",nullable = false,length = 10)
private RoleType roleType;

@Size(max = 50)
@Column(name = "description",length = 50)
private String description;

}


DDL by Hibernate -

alter table users 
   add constraint UK_pkddbcvou26qe5hsawu1mbnlb **unique** (role_id)
```

But i dont want **unique** (role_id) in my users table as many users can be assign to a single role.
Is it due to one to one mapping.is there a way to say dont create unique (role_id) in users table.
Even i tried with @JoinColumn(name = "role_id",unique=false) but no luck.Can any body help here.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this using @ManyToOne(optional=false) in users table like below.But not sure is this the right way or not but it solved my problem.

```
@JoinColumn(name="role_id")
@ManyToOne(optional=false)
private Role role;
```

Comment: *as many users can be assign to a single role*. Well clearly it is not a `OneToOne` as in your original code but a `ManyToOne` as per your update. If it is mapped as a `OneToOne` i.e. one role <-> one user then obviously the unique makes perfect sense.